GAM in R, model and assumptions
I have the following problem: My moderation analysis shows non-linearity. Thus, I try to fit a GAM. I have several problems:

My DV is left-skewed with many high and just some low values.
When fitting the model, I do not have enough k for 1 Variable but increasing k does not help.
I have high concurvity.

I am relatively new to this topic and the last days did not help to find an answer.
Here is my code: I have several models:
model_gam <- mgcv::gam(ipv_variety ~ s(dar_scaled) +
     s(age_scaled, k = 12) + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled), 
     data = merged_all_complete, method = "REML")

model_gam2 <- mgcv::gam(ipv_variety ~ te(dar_scaled, k = 12) + 
     te(age_scaled, k = 13) + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled), 
     data = merged_all_complete)

#alternative
gam1 <- lm(ipv_variety ~ ns(dar_scaled, 5) * age_scaled, 
          data=merged_all_complete)

mgcv::gam.check(model_gam)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 12 iterations.
Gradient range [-4.809951e-05,4.615121e-05]
(score 251.5576 & scale 2.881421).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [7.643802e-06,62.50661].
Model rank =  37 / 37 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                             k'   edf k-index p-value  
s(dar_scaled)              9.00  1.00    0.94   0.260  
s(age_scaled)             11.00  1.00    0.86   0.045 *
ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled) 16.00  2.29    0.98   0.365  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

mgcv::gam.check(model_gam2)

Method: GCV   Optimizer: magic
Smoothing parameter selection converged after 18 iterations.
The RMS GCV score gradient at convergence was 1.247369e-07 .
The Hessian was positive definite.
Model rank =  40 / 40 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                             k'   edf k-index p-value  
te(dar_scaled)            11.00  2.78    0.96    0.29  
te(age_scaled)            12.00  1.00    0.84    0.02 *
ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled) 16.00  2.95    1.02    0.52  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

concurvity(model_gam)
             para s(dar_scaled) s(age_scaled) ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled)
worst    0.686332     0.9685481     0.9463088                 0.9723609
observed 0.686332     0.4515971     0.7249471                 0.4033396
estimate 0.686332     0.4769273     0.7471936                 0.2483518
> concurvity(model_gam2)
              para te(dar_scaled) te(age_scaled) ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled)
worst    0.7006861      0.9708301      0.9635877                 0.9779052
observed 0.7006861      0.5241473      0.7229355                 0.4458624
estimate 0.7006861      0.2949492      0.3336875                 0.2602797

I tried out to penalise with bs = "ps", that did not help the concurvity. I do not know which method is best, default vs. REML show similar results. I can't find the correct distribution. Currently it is Gaussian.
Thank you so much in advance.

Thank you all so much. I have tried ocat() first as it seemed most intuitively for me. Here is the code:
model_gam <- mgcv::gam(variety_factor ~ s(dar_scaled) + s(age_scaled) + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled),family = ocat(R = 6), data = merged_all_complete, method = "REML")
mgcv::gam.check(model_gam)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 9 iterations.
Gradient range [-7.679113e-05,8.173563e-05]
(score 197.7688 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [1.616888e-05,26.12665].
Model rank =  35 / 35 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                             k'   edf k-index p-value  
s(dar_scaled)              9.00  1.00    0.87   0.085 .
s(age_scaled)              9.00  1.00    0.87   0.110  
ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled) 16.00  3.22    0.92   0.150  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> concurvity(model_gam)
              para s(dar_scaled) s(age_scaled) ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled)
worst    0.6830599     0.9678004     0.9454623                 0.9718880
observed 0.6830599     0.4472127     0.7249406                 0.3704958
estimate 0.6830599     0.4716231     0.7365367                 0.2378681

As edf for both IV was 1 I thought of leaving out the smoothes for these variables:
model_gam <- mgcv::gam(variety_factor ~ dar_scaled + age_scaled + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled),family = ocat(R = 6), data = merged_all_complete, method = "REML")
> summary.gam(model_gam)

Family: Ordered Categorical(-1,-0.15,0.3,0.9,1.71) 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
variety_factor ~ dar_scaled + age_scaled + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.34274    0.17195   7.809 5.77e-15 ***
dar_scaled   0.76810    0.18242   4.211 2.55e-05 ***
age_scaled   0.02831    0.17774   0.159    0.873    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                            edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value
ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled) 3.225  4.646  3.591    0.65

Deviance explained = 5.92%
-REML = 197.76  Scale est. = 1         n = 129
> #Check assumptions
> mgcv::gam.check(model_gam)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 7 iterations.
Gradient range [-4.360928e-06,-8.117468e-07]
(score 197.761 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [0.08851426,26.12667].
Model rank =  19 / 19 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                             k'   edf k-index p-value
ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled) 16.00  3.23    0.92    0.16
> concurvity(model_gam)
              para ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled)
worst    0.2180838                0.47804961
observed 0.2180838                0.06938545
estimate 0.2180838                0.04296387
> #Check assumptions
> mgcv::gam.check(model_gam)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 7 iterations.
Gradient range [-4.360928e-06,-8.117468e-07]
(score 197.761 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [0.08851426,26.12667].
Model rank =  19 / 19 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                             k'   edf k-index p-value
ti(dar_scaled,age_scaled) 16.00  3.23    0.92    0.16

My main problem are the normality plots:


Because of the 2 distributions the model does not fit, correct?
PS: This only works when I have categories with numbers from 1 upwards thus adding a 1 to my categories 0:5 (http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/mgcv/html/ocat.html), otherwise i get this error:
merged_all_complete$variety_factor <- as.integer(merged_all_complete$ipv_variety)
> merged_all_complete$variety_factor
  [1] 1 3 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 4 5 1 0 0 5 3 3 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 4 4 3 5 5 5 5 1 5 5 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 2 5 5 5 4 5 5
 [61] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 0 2 1 1 3 3 4 2 1 0 0 4 0 3 0 0 3 4 5 3 5 5 3 4 0 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 4 2 5 5 5 5 4 3 4 1 1 0 4
[121] 4 3 1 2 3 4 5 5 2
> #Alternative as interaction term seems to be non-linear
> model_gam <- mgcv::gam(variety_factor ~ dar_scaled + age_scaled + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled),family = ocat(R = 6), data = merged_all_complete, method = "REML")
Error in eval(family$initialize) : values out of range

Thanks again for all of your help and support. I greatly appreciate it.

Can you please reformat the code in this question so it is readable? If you click on Edit in your question, the Body section has a part that looks like { } , which you can use to add code to your question. As it stands, this question is difficult to answer. It would also be helpful to explain the nature of your DV (basically what does it measure). What may be contributing to it's skewness and limited range? This would also help with getting answers about the proper GAM model here.

It should be reformatted (at least I see it that way).

My DV measures the number of different intimate partner forms experienced by the women in my sample. If you have experienced sexual and emotional or physical and control IPV you will get the value 2, and so on. Interestingly, in my sample most have experienced all forms of IPV (value 5). Short info, there are 5 subtypes and thus DV can have values from 0 to 5. I tested whether I can add these different IPV forms to 1 variable via Rasch model, and I can do it.

I wonder if a better approach, then, would be to approach this as a multi-label problem, where each woman can experience any combination (including all or none) of the IPV types, same as how an image may contain a dog, cat, horse, any combination of the three animals, or none of the animals.

I am not sure whether I understand it correctly. But I decided in my dv variety score that I don´t care about the specific combination. I rather want to see the amount of different forms experienced. And this should be modelled with the 2 IV (DAR measures anger, which is my independent variable, age is the men´s age and my moderator). Unfortunately, they don´t seem to be correlated linearly and thus I need another model. Polynomial would also be possible but I simply don´t know which polynomial functions to use, as I want to avoid overfitting.

In light of the points raised in the comments, here are some suggestions for ways to handle the response:

if you can consider the response as an ordered categorical variable (0 = no IPV, 1 = 1 instance of IPV, 2 = 2 instances of IPV, etc), then family = ocat(R = 6) might work.

Alternatively, you could also think of the response as representing "a number of IPV instances" experienced out of a total (5), in which case perhaps family = binomial() might work.

Related to @Dave's comment (although note that they suggested viewing this as a multilabel problem, not a multiclass problem as I suggest here), perhaps it might be better to approach this as a multinomial with 5 classes (each IPV form), where the 0 experience would just be a 0 on all 5 classes. In that case, try family = multinomial(K = 4) (there are K + 1 = 5 categories).


The problem I see with at least the binomial and possibly the ordered categorical model is that there are likely to be correlations among the categories; subject 1 experiences IPV 2 and hence is more likely to also experience 4 as those two kinds of IPV tend to occur together and hence the "events" are not independent (I'm making all this up - I have no idea about IPVs). This will likely show up as extra dispersion.
You should probably fit the model with method = "REML" if you continue to use mgcv; it will be forced with family = multinomial() anyway.
In your model_gam2, don't use univariate te() smooths; replace these two with univariate ti() so that everything matches with the bivariate ti() also in that model.
All of your splines are penalised; switching to bs = "ps" won't help in that regard as it just switches to a P-spline basis with a difference-based penalty. The other splines use derivative based penalties and are also penalised.
I suspect the gam.check() thing is related to the smooth for age_scaled being estimated at 1 EDF so its a linear function. But don't worry about this until you fix the distribution issue for the response - the Gaussian isn't the right model here so who cares if the basis dimension test is failing for this wrong model!
In your concurvity() calls, use full = FALSE so you can see which terms are concurved with which other model terms. And again, do this after you have an approximately correct model.

I don’t see it is multinomial/multiclass. I see it as multi-label.

@Dave I was thinking if you don't turn the probability of the classes into a winner-takes all prediction, this might still work; each class would get it's own linear predictor, so the output would be a matrix of probabilities. But I see that I misrepresented your actual comment. Will fix that.

Thank you so much! Could I ask 2 more questions that are probably easy to answer? First, why ti() and not te()? I just saw a video/presentation on YouTube and he presented the example as in my model 2 (Minute 20: youtube.com/watch?v=q4_t8jXcQgc). Second, then I need my DV as a factor with merged_all_complete$factor_variety<−factor(merged_all_complete$ipv_variety, levels = 0:5), correct?

Wrt to the ti() specification, this allows you to exclude the main effects from the interaction after including them elsewhere in the model. This is similar to allowing a main effect and an interaction in a standard regression rather than just the interaction by itself. The te() function just estimates a smooth between two variables without decomposing their independent effects separately.

You can use te() like this; I just don't like it and in the past Simon Wood threatened to remove univariate tensor products from mgcv. He has since removed the threat from the notes at the top of the changelog, but still... I think the intention of code is important; so i would write it as s(x1, bs = "cr") + s(x2, bs = "cr") + ti(x1, x2) of this ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1, x2) as the intention is clearer. But as it happens there is no difference in this case to using te(x1) or ti(x1).

Thank you all! I have tried ocat() as that was the most intuitive approach (the categories are ordered as 2 forms of IPV experienced are more than 3 forms). My IVs are linearly related to dv (edf of  1), just interaction seems to be non-linear. Unfortunately, the concurvity is high. As a consequence, I reformulated the model: model_gam <- mgcv::gam(variety_factor ~ dar_scaled + age_scaled + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled),family = ocat(R = 6), data = merged_all_complete, method = "REML") My main point is that in gam.check() linearity of residuals is not given(Histogram: bimodal distribution).
